# Unable to compile libcurl with CMake, unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl

Im trying to compile libcurl on Win10 with my project in CMake. Currently this is (the libcurl part of) my setup:

```
link_directories("C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64-1_1_1/lib")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64-1_1_1")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0/src)
add_subdirectory(curl-7.80.0)
```

When doing so I get these errors:

> Creating library C:/PATH/build/curl-7.80.0/lib/Debug/libcurl-d_imp.lib and object C:/PATH/build/curl-7.80.0/lib/Debug/libcurl-d_imp.exp
>
> libssh2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol libssh2_init referenced in function Curl_ssh_init [C:\PATH\curl-7.80.0\build\lib\libcurl.vcxproj]
>
> libssh2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol libssh2_exit referenced in function Curl_ssh_cleanup
> [C:\PATH\curl-7.80.0\build\lib\libcurl.vcxproj]
>
> libssh2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol libssh2_session_init_ex referenced in function ssh_force_kno
> wnhost_key_type
> [C:\PATH\curl-7.80.0\build\lib\libcurl.vcxproj]
>
> libssh2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol libssh2_session_abstract referenced in function sftp_perform
> [C:\PATH\curl-7.80.0\build\lib\libcurl.vcxproj]

OpenSSL was installed via this installer: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

I dont really know much about CMake, typically enough to build my own projects, but this is a bit over my head. I gladly appreciate every help you can give me.

Edit 1: actual link command as given by CMake:

> Link:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\PATH\bin\64bit_\Debug\libcurl-d.dll" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"libcurl.dir
> Debug\libcurl-d.ilk" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64-1_1_1/lib" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files/OpenSS
> L-Win64-1_1_1/lib/Debug" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64-1_1_1" /LIBPATH:"C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64-
> 1_1_1/Debug" /LIBPATH:"C:/PATH/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0/src" /LIBPATH:"C:/PATH/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0/src/Debug" /LIBPATH:"C:/PATH/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2
> -1.10.0" /LIBPATH:"C:/PATH/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0/Debug" wldap32.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.
> lib "......\out\build\x64-Debug\libssh2-1.10.0\src\libssh2.lib" advapi32.lib crypt32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib
> gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTU
> AC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/PATH/bin/64bit_/Debug/libc
> url-d.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/PATH/build/curl-7.80.0/l
> ib/Debug/libcurl-d_imp.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /DLL libcurl.dir\Debug\libcurl.res

Edit 2: dumpbin for libssh2_exit

> 00C 00000050 SECT4  notype ()    External     | libssh2_exit
>
> 01B 00000008 SECT5  notype       Static       | $unwind$libssh2_exit
>
> 01C 0000000C SECT6  notype       Static       | $pdata$libssh2_exit

Comment: Note that ss**h** is different from ss**l**. Perhaps it suffices to turn off ssh/scp support in curl? Alternatively, use conan/vcpkg. be happy.

Comment: @Botje I added link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0/src)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/out/build/x64-Debug/libssh2-1.10.0) but this didnt change anything. Id like to not use a package manager to make libcurl part of my project

Comment: `link_directories` only tells the linker _where_ to look. You need to actually tell it to link with libssh2 as well.

Comment: @Botje how would I do this from outside? libcurl tells me it found the libssh2 libs (respectively it doesnt tell me that it didnt found them)

Comment: Ah. Would be handy if that was in your question. The lack of `x64` in the curl build path makes me wonder if you're actually building 32bit mode, then.

Comment: So youre saying Im trying to build x64 (which is my intend) but libcurl defaults to x86 and thus the libs are not compatible?

Comment: I'm just wondering, but I don't know how you invoked CMake or which platform you selected in visual studio. libcurl can of course be compiled in both flavors.

Comment: Show the actual link command (run `make VERBOSE=1` to see it).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I edited the post, showing the link command

Comment: @Botje VS is only the toolchain, Im compiling with console (for reasons that go back a few days of error search...)

Comment: What does `dumpbin /symbols ...\out\build\x64-Debug\libssh2-1.10.0\src\libssh2.lib` have to say about `libssh2_exit`?

Comment: So it seems you are linking with the static version of libssh2, but the dynamic version of libcurl. I don't think this can work on Windows (it should work on Unix-y systems).  Try using the DLL version of libssh2.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Even after building libssh2 to a DLL libcurl still tries to build a static lib. I cant find any ressources about how to force libcurl to make a DLL, Google is full of "trouble making static libcurl"

Comment: hmm no sorry, you are *building* libcurl, not *using* libcurl. `/OUT:"C:\PATH\bin\64bit_\Debug\libcurl-d.dll"` says you are building a libcurl DLL. It should work with static libssh2 then. I don't really know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer this:

libcurl wasnt trying to build with OpenSSl, I neede to use a flag -DCMAKE_USE_OPENSSL to get libcurl to use it. Further my installer installed two different libs, OpenSSL and OpenSSL-1_1_1. The second one brought an error, the first one was a success